# How to use the command "cut" to cut out fields in a CSV file when fields contain commas?

Tags: text-processing

CSV files format Data like the following

```
"Pizza,wings,icecream","hopper","0",,"Masdfasdf","USA","381","10 AM","cap",,,"monster"
```

Using a comma as the delimiter such as below will result in fields with commas to be counted as delimiters, which is not what i want.

```
cat /path/to/file | cut -d , -f2
```

will return

```
wings
```

when i want

```
hopper
```

I think i have found a solution logically, but i am unsure how to implement it.

How would i make a delimiter that would say "If i am a comma, surrounded by either another comma or quotes, count me as a delimiter"?

---

**Example**

```
[tksmith@rifle ~]$ cat deleteme 

"Pizza,wings,icecream","hopper","0",,"Masdfasdf","USA","381","10 AM","cap",,,"monster"

[tksmith@rifle ~]$ cat deleteme | cut -d , -f2

wings
```

Comment: You can define all those options that you mentioned as your delimiter.

Comment: I double checked myself and this is not my case, i added an example of the command i just did.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? there are dedicated CSV parsers such as perl's `Text::CSV` or `csvtool` that can do this out-of-the-box e.g. `csvtool col 2 file.csv`

Comment: or `csvkit` e.g. `csvcut -c2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cut command command only delimits one character at a time. So you could transform the quotes and commas into another single character delimiter using sed and a regexp. For example:

```
sed -e 's/","\|",\|,"\|,,/@/g' /path/to/file | cut -d@ -f2
```

Will return

```
hopper
```

Another way is to use AWK. For example the following would give you the 2nd field.

```
awk -F ',,|^"|","|",|,"|"$' '{print $3}' /path/to/file
```

will return

```
hopper
```

The above examples aren't perfect as they don't handle all correctly all the cases with multiple empty fields and outside quotes. Best to use a higher level scripting language with a CSV parsing module.

Comment: Using `awk`, he can get `hopper` with `awk -F , '{print substr($4,2,6)}'`. It does the same thing that your `awk` command does but it's a bit shorter.

Comment: Nasir, the awk example in my attempts to delimit based on the the quoted text. Your awk example takes the fourth value after a comma and selects 6 characters starting at the 2nd position. The OP's question was how to get quoted values between delimiters -- the delimiters can be inside the quotes.

Comment: In his example above, he said that he wanted `hopper` as the output. That is the output that your answer provides and the same thing that my command provides. My command does what you said but it gives the exact same output as yours so who cares? He can account for quoted values by using my example and printing a substring to get a value inside the quotes. He specified a certain output in his question so if he wants something else under different circumstances, he needs to modify the syntax. Bottom line, my command gives the same output as yours with less code so why not use the easier way?

Comment: For his example, none of the commas, which he specifies as the delimiter, are inside of quotes but let's say that there was a part of the file where a delimiter was inside of quotes. Take the section of `"10 AM"` and let's say that the space inside is a delimiter and he wants `AM` as the output. Either `awk '{print substr($2,1,2)}' deleteme` or `awk -F , '{print substr($10,5,2)}' deleteme` will work. Whether the delimiter is inside the quotes or not, there's no need to add more work where it isn't necessary.

Comment: Nasir, first of all his example does have commas inside the quotes. Second his question was: _How would i make a delimiter that would say "If i am a comma, surrounded by either another comma or quotes, count me as a delimiter"?_
"

Comment: No single comma is surrounded by quotes and it doesn't matter even if one of them were. `awk -F , '{print substr}` sets the delimiter as a comma and prints anything after it regardless of where the quotes are. My examples prove this and show that the quotes don't need to be accounted for so you bringing up that part of his question is irrelevant and pointless. If he wanted to get `wings` then he could just `awk -F , '{print $2)'` with no regards to where the quotes are. You don't need the extra rigmarole that's in your answer as it just complicates things unnecessarily and I've shown this.

Comment: `awk -F , '{print $2)'` prints `wings` regardless of the quotes and `awk -F , '{print substr($7,2,9)}' deleteme` prints `Masdfasdf` despite the comma being next to another one. That shows that what you keep bringing up doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

CSV format has enough edge cases that you don't want to reinvent parsing it. Use a proper CSV parser. For example, with ruby

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|row| puts row[1]}' file
```

Comment: perl's Text::CSV is more robust if the quoted fields can contain newlines.